# Java Login Error, can not be resolved to variable

Tags: java, variables, authentication

I'm building a log in system for a java program which will be working out employees wages for certain stores. 
Before I go any further I am fully aware this isn't the safest way to make a log in so please don't try explaining because I'm aware. 
My code so far is below

```
public class project15 
{
public static void main(String[] args);
{ 
String store = store501;
String stroePin = 1468dty;
String personalPin = abc123;
String inputStore;
String inputPin;
String inputPersonal
inputStore = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter the store number");
inputPin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter the stores unique ID");
inputPersonal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter your persoanl ID");
if (inputStore==store && inputPin==stroePin && inputPersonal==personalPin){
System.out.println("correct information");
}
else 
{
System.out.println("incorrect information");
}
}
}
```

I get an error on the first three String values saying, for example, "store501 can not be resolved to a variable. " Everything else seems to be working okay. Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong and please explain as I am eager to learn from any mistakes I may have made. Thanks in advance and I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: You need to put quotes : `String store = "store501";` _"A string literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed in double quotes"_  `StringLiteral:
        " StringCharacters "`

Comment: fyi, you have a typo's in: stroePin->storePin  "please enter your persoanl ID"->"please enter your personal ID"

Comment: also you're comparing strings using `str1==str2` instead of `str1.equals(str2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `store501`, `1468dty` and `abc123` are variables that are not defined.

You must define them before using. Something like:

```
String store501 = "some string";
```

Or maybe you want them to be `Strings`. In that case:

```
String store =  "store501"; // Strings are between ""
```

Read more about `Strings` in [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), or [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

**Remember:**

To compare `String` use:

```
str1.equals(str2)
```

not

```
str1 == str2
```

Read this "[How to compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)"

Comment: I've just done this and now I get "incorrect information" printed to the screen if I type the correct or incorrect information

Comment: Strings are compared with `equals` see edit. And read more about that please.

Comment: Thank you I've just read through that it's very helpful information, just wondering is there a way to shut down the program if someone types in the wrong information 10 times?

Comment: Try a `while` or a `for` loop. One time more, you can read about them in [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [here for while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one mistake in your program.  First, there's what everybody else said about declaring your String constants.  But then there's another mistake too.

You are using == to compare Strings.  The Java expression a == b compares two variables and it returns true if both variables reference the same Object.  It does *not* compare the objects to see whether or not they have the same value.

Your program could set personalPin="abc123"; and the user could type in abc123 when prompted for inputPersonal, and yet personalPin and inputPersonal are likely to refer to two different String objects that both happen to have the same value.  That is to say, personalPin==inputPersonal could be false even though both strings are "abc123".

The way to fix it is to use the String.equals() function to compare the contents of the Strings:

personalPin.equals(inputPersonal)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a String you need to surround it with ""

```
String store = "store501";
String stroePin = "1468dty";
String personalPin = "abc123";
String inputStore;
String inputPin;
String inputPersonal
inputStore = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter the store number");
inputPin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter the stores unique ID");
inputPersonal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter your persoanl ID");
if (store.equals(inputStore) && stroePin.equals(inputPin) && personalPin.equals(inputPersonal)){
  System.out.println("correct information");
} else {
  System.out.println("incorrect information");
}
```

Comment: I've just done this and now I get "incorrect information" printed to the screen if I type the correct or incorrect information

Comment: never compare strings with == . You should always use .equals(). I'll update the code above for you

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
String store = "store501";
String stroePin = "1468dty";
String personalPin = "abc123";
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are string variables then you should place them within "".You can either do it this way:

```
String store = "store501";
String stroePin = "1468dty";
String personalPin = "abc123";
```

OR:

```
String store;
String stroePin;
String personalPin;
store="store501";
stroePin="1468dty";
personalPin="abc123";
```